# Please explain blend mode bm_dest_color for blending image data

Tags: javascript, blending

I need blend image data. I do not know how to explain it, so I show it.

I cant write links because my reputation is minimal, so [here is directory with images online](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B92s8VQnMclYTnF5STBXdi13ODA&usp=sharing).

I have **destination image** as in link above.
*FirstStep.png* I draw to black image with alpha 0.5. result image is **Source image**

when I draw **Source image** to **destination image** result is as *sourceimage on destination*

I need blend mode for result like *final.png*

This Im made one nameless game engine. I need do this same on html canvas. on nameless game engine I do it with this

```
draw_set_blend_mode_ext(bm_dest_color,bm_normal);
'destination image'.draw('Source image')//some like this
```

in documentation from nameless game engine is written this

> draw_set_blend_mode_ext(src,dest) Indicates what blend mode to use for both the source and destination color. The new color is some factor times the source and another factor times the destination. These factors are set with this function. To understand this, the source and destination both have a red, green, blue, and alpha component. So the source is (Rs, Gs, Bs, As) and the destination is (Rd, Gd, Bd, Ad). All are considered to lie between 0 and 1. The blend factors you can choose for source and destination are:
>
> - bm_zero: Blend factor is (0, 0, 0, 0).
> - bm_dest_color: Blend factor is (Rd, Gd, Bd, Ad).

can somebody help me make some like `draw_set_blend_mode_ext(bm_dest_color,bm_normal);` for JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Im found the solution.
Im used GlobalCompositeOperation *source-atop*
here is result http://1.popokecal.appspot.com/